# Rearrange object properties by name

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var json = {
    displayImage1: {
        object: "style1"
    },
    displayImage4: {
        object: "style2"
    },
    displayImage3: {
        object: "style3"
    }
};
```

is there any way I can arrange my object values by number? So it would be:

```
displayImage1
displayImage3
displayImage4
```

Comment: Your question is rather moot as the properties of an object cannot be ordered. If you need this behaviour you would need to use an array of objects instead.

Comment: do the names always follow that "convention" - means is the number displayed at the end anytime?

Comment: An object is, [by definition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf), an *unordered* collection of properties. The fact that a box can have both a height and a width says nothing about the order in which it has height and size. A representation of the properties of an object can have an inherent order, however. `Object.keys(json)`, for instance, yields an array of strings, which can be sorted in any manner you like. Is this what you are requesting?